# Need to remove ROWSET and ROW tags from generated xml Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle

I'm running below sql query in Oracle

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml( 'SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ''mm/dd/yyyy'') CURRENT_DATE,NAME,VERSION, (SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''compatible'') compatible,
(SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''optimizer_mode'') optimizer_mode,
             log_mode, open_mode, logins AS logon_status,
 (TO_CHAR (created, ''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'')) created 
 FROM v$database, v$instance') from dual;
```

It gives me bwloe output xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <CURRENT_DATE>12/10/2019</CURRENT_DATE>
  <NAME>PROD2</NAME>
  <VERSION>19.0.0.0.0</VERSION>
  <COMPATIBLE>19.0.0</COMPATIBLE>
  <OPTIMIZER_MODE>ALL_ROWS</OPTIMIZER_MODE>
  <LOG_MODE>ARCHIVELOG</LOG_MODE>
  <OPEN_MODE>READ WRITE</OPEN_MODE>
  <LOGON_STATUS>ALLOWED</LOGON_STATUS>
  <CREATED>11/07/2019 13:10</CREATED>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

This the output I'm looking for but I don't want ROWSET and ROW tags. I tried XML context but it is getting some errors I'm unable to resolve.

```
DECLARE
   ctx DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
   xml CLOB;
BEGIN
ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext( 'SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ''mm/dd/yyyy'') CURRENT_DATE,NAME,VERSION, (SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''compatible'') compatible,
(SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''optimizer_mode'') optimizer_mode,
             log_mode, open_mode, logins AS logon_status,
 (TO_CHAR (created, ''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'')) created 
 FROM v$database, v$instance from dual');
  dbms_xmlgen.setRowTag(ctx, 'NUMBERS');
   xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);
END;
```

Errors:
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 7
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLGEN", line 147
ORA-06512: at line 15

Actually I'm new to Oracle DB queries. Can anybody help me with the proper query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue is, that your query in the second block isn't syntactically correct:

```
FROM v$database, v$instance from dual');
```

If you omit `from dual`, it seems to be working OK. Tested on:

```
DECLARE
   ctx DBMS_XMLGEN.ctxHandle;
   xml CLOB;
BEGIN
ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newcontext( 'SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, ''mm/dd/yyyy'') CURRENT_DATE,NAME,VERSION, (SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''compatible'') compatible,
(SELECT VALUE
                FROM v$parameter
               WHERE NAME = ''optimizer_mode'') optimizer_mode,
             log_mode, open_mode, logins AS logon_status,
 (TO_CHAR (created, ''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'')) created 
 FROM v$database, v$instance');
  dbms_xmlgen.setrowsettag(ctx, 'NUMBERS');
  dbms_xmlgen.setrowtag(ctx, '');
   xml := dbms_xmlgen.getxml(ctx);
   dbms_output.put_line(xml);
END;
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<NUMBERS>
 <CURRENT_DATE>12/10/2019</CURRENT_DATE>
 <NAME>XXX</NAME>
 <VERSION>12.2.0.1.0</VERSION>
 <COMPATIBLE>12.2.0</COMPATIBLE>
 <OPTIMIZER_MODE>ALL_ROWS</OPTIMIZER_MODE>
 <LOG_MODE>NOARCHIVELOG</LOG_MODE>
 <OPEN_MODE>READ WRITE</OPEN_MODE>
 <LOGON_STATUS>ALLOWED</LOGON_STATUS>
 <CREATED>01/01/2000 00:00</CREATED>
</NUMBERS>
```

Hope that helped.